# How to communicate between the Views in the Silverlight 3.0 application?

Tags: silverlight-3.0, navigation, communication

I am building a Silverlight 3.0 app based on the Silverlight Navigation Application template.  One road block I ran into is communicating between the Pages.  For instance, I am in one Page, and I want to kick off another page and send it some data.  I am at a loss as to how to do this.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you mean send it some data from the originating page or send a request to the server and have the new page get the response?

Comment: Oh, and are you using MVVM?  And/or WCF RIA Services?  
I've read a few of your recent questions - I'm also building a Silverlight 3 Navigation app and I'm hitting similar issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found an effective solution that does not involve too much complexity.  I am using the [LocalMessageSender](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.messaging.localmessagesender(VS.95).aspx) and [LocalMessageReceiver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.messaging.localmessagereceiver(VS.95).aspx) objects. The original purpose of these objects are to have 2 silverlight apps on the same web page talk to each, but it's just as good at having 2 views talk to each other.

The usage is really straight-forward.  See this [example](http://www.wintellect.com/CS/blogs/jprosise/archive/2009/03/26/silverlight-3-s-new-local-connections.aspx) for usage.

Answer (score 1):

Jesse Liberty has an excellent [blog post](http://jesseliberty.com/2008/05/31/multi-page-applications-in-silverlight/) about just this. I use the techniques described there myself in a multi page Silverlight application.

I'm not sure though whether you can apply this with the Silverlight Navigation Application template.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 options

1. Use Publish/Subscribe pattern, i havent used this before, but it is useful in certain cases, i dont think it would solve ur problem though.
2. Use Request parameters, basically when you navigate to the new view, call it like so

   NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/HomePage.xaml?HomePageId=12", UriKind.Relative));

You could slap some string.format in there to make it neater, but you get the idea, then on the new View, use `string queryParam = HtmlPage.Document.QueryString["HomePageId"];` on page load to get the Id of the information you wish to display.

That should do it.